# Bases de datos multples con django

Tags: base-de-datos, django, rest

Hola estoy intentando usar varias bases de datos  he seguido la documentación y varios ejemplos que he visto pero los modelos diseccionados por el router que he creado no se crean en ninguna base de datos.

```
    class dbRouter(object):
"""
A router to control all database operations on models in the
auth application.
"""
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'compra':
        return 'compra_database'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'compra':
        return 'compra_database'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
    """
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'compra' or \
       obj2._meta.app_label == 'compra':
       return True        
    return True

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
    database.
    """
    if app_label == 'compra':
        return db == 'compra_database'
    return None
```

y estas las opciones del archivo settings.

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'Django',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'R4spb3rryPi_8d',
     },
     'auth_database': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'Django',
    'USER': 'XXXXXXXXX',
    'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
       },
    'compra_database': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'Compras',
    'USER': 'XXXXXXXXX',
    'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
     },
     'crohn_database': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'Crohn',
    'USER': 'XXXXXXXXX',
    'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    },
    }

    DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['raspi.dbrouter.dbRouter']
```

los comandos makemigrations crean tablas de migración en todas las bases de datos y migrate no tira ningún error pero sin embargo solo aparecen las tablas de auth, session y contrib que aparecen en la base de datos Default.

un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Las base de datos no se crean automáticamente, tienes que crearlas manualmente. Una vez has creado las BDs corre las migraciones y tus tablas de deberían de crear en sus respectivas BDs

Comment: Hola, si el proceso que comentas ya lo he llevado a cabo pero no funciona, al parecer es un problema de Django lo he solucionado usando el comando: python migrate.py migrate nombre _app - - database:base_de_datos

Comment: los modelos por defecto se crean en una base de datos   cuando hagas los migrate el problema es al cambiar de base de datos al hacer la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Las clases en python se definene con mayúsculas

```
class DbRouter(object)
```

en vez de

```
class dbRouter(object):
```